# Python 2 - Reverse-sorting python dictionary without damaging data in nested dictionaries

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a python script that prints out a dictionary with nested dictionaries for values.
This script's output is caught by a java automation script that has to has to have the dictionary's keys in a specific order.

The java automation expects the output the be {'pass': {blah bla bla}, 'fail': {}}.
The output of my python code is always {'fail':{},'pass':{blah blah blah}}.

The java automation treats the outputted dictionary as a JSON and looks for the value in the first key (because it needs to do stuff with what passed, not with what failed).

I tried printing the dictionary reverse-sorted, but then the values in the nested dictionaries are lost and all I get is {'pass':{},'fail':{}}.

Whenever I try to look for sorting dictionaries WITH nested dictionaries, I only get solutions for sorting the nested dictionaries themselves.

Here's the python code:

```
def totalPcapTransmission(directory):

copiedPcaps = []
failedPcaps = []
transportDictionaryTrans = {}
passFailDictionary = {"pass": {}, "fail": {}}

transportDictionaryTrans = createAPcapDictionary(jsonDirectory + 'Pcaps')
getThemGWCredentials(jsonDirectory)
execCMD('noOutput', 'mkdir /opt/SecureSphere/etc/pcap_files')

pcap2Transport = commands.getoutput(
    'ls ' + directory+'/finalDir').replace("\n", " ").split()
for pcap in pcap2Transport:
    try:
        execSCP(pcap, directory)
        time.sleep(10)
        copiedPcaps.append(pcap)
    except OSError as errMSG:
        print"Pcap {}'s copy to GW went wrong, and here's what happened: {}".format(pcap, errorMSG)
    except:
        e = sys.exc_info()[0]
        failedPcaps.append(pcap)
        print"Pcap {}'s copy to GW went wrong, and here's what happened: {}".format(pcap, e)

execCMD('noOutput', 'find /opt/SecureSphere/etc/pcap_files/ -type f -delete')

failDict = {y: transportDictionaryTrans.get(
    y) for y in failedPcaps if y in transportDictionaryTrans.keys()}
passFailDictionary["fail"].update(failDict)
copyDict = {x: transportDictionaryTrans.get(
    x) for x in copiedPcaps if x in transportDictionaryTrans.keys()}
passFailDictionary["pass"].update(copyDict)

print passFailDictionary
```

I inherited the java automation and I'm also just starting to learn java so I don't know how to fix things on the java side yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There's a useful module called [collections](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) which has an `OrderedDict` type. Make one of those from your `passFailDictionary`, with the keys sorted accordingly, and print the result.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
sortedPFD = OrderedDict(sorted(passFailDictionary.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[0]))
print json.dumps(sortedPFD)
```

The `.items()` gives you an unsorted list of (key, value) pairs, where the key is either `'pass'` or `'fail'`. Then the `sorted(...., key=....)` sorts it by the first element of the pair, which is the key.

Comment: That gets me this output:
OrderedDict([('pass':{blah blah blah},'fail':{})])
Not the data structure I need.

Comment: Good point! I was concentrating on the sorting, sorry! Corrected now.